# make some drag-able UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'd like to make some drag-able UIView.
But in case of following code, you can drag only one UIView you have added at the last.

[image]

I have this code.
LabelView class is subclass of UIView.

ViewControlle.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) LabelView* labelView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _labelView = [[LabelView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:_labelView];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
    [_labelView addGestureRecognizer:pan];

    UIButton* addButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 60, 40, 40)];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(newLabelView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:addButton];
}

- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint p = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint movedPoint = CGPointMake(_labelView.center.x + p.x, _labelView.center.y + p.y);
    _labelView.center = movedPoint;
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}

- (void)newLabelView
{
    _labelView = [[LabelView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 200, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:_labelView];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
    [_labelView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mutable array, and then add each new view into that array. You do this by adding:

```
NSMutableArray *viewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// after creating the custom view
[viewsArray addObject:customView];
```

Then, you can add a pan gesture on top of the views in the array, that way they are all using the pan gesture

```
for(LabelView *l in viewsArray) {
    [l addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

this will add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to all the custom views in the array that you created in the beginning of this answer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the getsture for all the view. and then change the methods.  `_labelView.center = movedPoint;` to `[sender view].center = movedPoint;`

```
 - (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint p = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint movedPoint = CGPointMake(_labelView.center.x + p.x, _labelView.center.y + p.y);
    [sender view].center = movedPoint;
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```